# SIMULINK - Ignoring Scope Block when using Embedded Code Generation

Tags: matlab, code-generation, output, simulink

I have got some inputs in my model that are passed through the *environment controller* block. In this way, I can use test inputs (fixed or configurable parameters) in simulation and the top-level input ports for Embedded Code Generation. However, I need to check the outputs of my model (after simulation) on a scope.

I was hoping that there is way I can use something similar to environment controller block in order to ignore scope blocks when I generate code. In this way, I can still view my outputs but not worry about any unnecessary blocks getting error-flagged during code generation checking. Is there any way to do it or is it "Automatically" ignored when generating code. Has anyone come across this?

KR,

Comment: Normally the practice is that the model from which you generate the code only has inputs and outputs, and for simulation/testing purposes is inserted into another model with scopes, inputs, etc... as a model reference.

Comment: You can also use a signal viewer or signal logging, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/about-scope-blocks-signal-viewers-signal-logging-and-test-points.html. I don't think these should affect code generation.

Comment: @am304          (after your first comment)agreed, but if you use environment controller it is slightly easier as it helps you minimise your overall testing time. So, if I understand what you are saying, there is not really any straightforward way to do it?

Comment: @am304         (after your second comment) Signal logging is not really useful for me as I don't want to plot them separately. I was hoping that I can use scope and ignore it when generating code. Signal logging is not my solution :(

Comment: @haugubear Signal viewer should allow you to plot them together.  Have a look at the video http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/simulink/description4.html. Do you get an error when trying to generate code from a model with a scope?

Comment: Scopes are ignored during code generation. Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: @Navan          That's all I needed to know. The reason I couldn't check it myself is because my Embedded Coder licence has not arrived and I was trying to do some derisking work with my model. Thanks for the information anyway.

Comment: Also worth checking the following: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/simulation-data-inspector-overview.html